# cURL XML POST works but not Python Requests - 3rd party Expert Rating API (w/ examples)

Tags: python, xml, django, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to make a POST request that sends XML data to a 3rd party server, it works with cmd line curl but not the [python requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (which I need to work). I've omitted out the username, password, and domain urls. I'm using requests==2.2.1

**CURL EXAMPLE (WORKS):**

Request:

```
$ curl --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><authentication partnerid="12345" password="mypass1234" /><method name="GetTestList" /></request>' 'http://dev.expertrating.com/mydomain/webservices/'
```

Response:

```
<response><result name="GetTestList"><records><record test_id="6683" test_name="Demo Adobe Photoshop CS3 Test" coverage="Layers ;Type ;Automating Tasks and Keyboard Shortcuts ;Workspace ;Working with Images, Retouching and Transforming ;Color Management ;Color and Tonal Adjustments ;Using Selection and Drawing ;Filters and Saving Images ;Working With Web, Video and Animation" total_questions="10" duration="10" passing_marks="60" category="Demo Tests" /><record test_id="6684" test_name="Demo Programming with C++ Test" coverage="Classes ;Constructors ;Variables and Datatypes" total_questions="10" duration="10" passing_marks="60" category="Demo Tests" /><record test_id="6685" test_name="Demo HTML 4.01 Test" coverage="Advanced Tags ;Fundamentals ;Tags ;Tables ;Links and Images ;Forms and Frames" total_questions="10" duration="10" passing_marks="60" category="Demo Tests" /><record test_id="6682" test_name="Demo Editing Skills Certification" coverage="Prepositions ;Parallel Construction ;Comma Usage ;Punctuation ;Misplaced Modifiers ;Apostrophe Usage ;Sentence Structure ;Pronoun Usage ;Tenses ;Article Usage" total_questions="10" duration="10" passing_marks="60" category="Demo Tests" /></records></result></response>
```

**REQUESTS EXAMPLE: (FAILS)** (via ipython/django)

IPython:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><authentication partnerid="12345" password="mypass1234" /><method name="GetTestList" /></request>'

In [3]: r = requests.post('http://dev.expertrating.com/mydomain/webservices/', data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})

In [4]: r.text
Out[4]: u"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><response><error id='101' message='Invalid Request'><info>You have not posted a valid request.</info></error></response>"
```

Am I encoding the requests string wrong? Including the wrong headers? I literally copy/pasted the urls and payload xml. I also tried POSTing with urllib2 with similar failing results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance to anyone who reads this.

Comment: Could you also include the output from running your curl command with `-v`. That said, the main difference between the two that I notice is in the former you do not send the Content-Type header. Perhaps your server is not accepting your requests posts for that reason. It seems curl would set a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: You're exactly correct thanks! Curl was sending `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so I used that instead of `application/xml` and it worked. Strange because the API wanted me to send raw xml data and never told me what headers to send in the specs. Oh well, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by setting the `Content-Type` header to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `Content-Type: application/xml`.